# How to fix Referenced sniff "PHPCompatibility.FunctionUse.RemovedFunctions" does not exist with PHP8.1

Tags: magento2.4, code-analysis, phpcs

For php8.1 and with the latest Magento coding standards we are facing below error while running the static test from CLI and PHPStorm

> ERROR: Referenced sniff "PHPCompatibility.FunctionUse.RemovedFunctions" does not exist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is known issue with Magento coding standards and temporary workaround is to add below code

```
$resolvedInstalledPaths[] = '/path/to/your/project/vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility/PHPCompatibility';

        $resolvedInstalledPaths[] = $installedPath;
    }

    return $resolvedInstalledPaths;
```

to

**\PHP_CodeSniffer\Util\Standards::getInstalledStandardPaths**

Answer (score 10):

Add the `phpcompatibility/php-compatibility` ruleset to the `composer.json` using `post-install-cmd`:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility)"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This usually works but there is issue with current version of phpcs sometime installed path are blank despite defining it

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it does not require manual changes in any file.

Answer (score 0):

None the suggestions present here helped me to fix GitHub actions. Instead, I've used the following:

1. Run `$ composer require --dev "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer"`.
2. Add in your composer.json the section ->

   ```
   "config": {"allow-plugins": {"dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true}}
   ```
3. If you're using `--no-dev` flag for composer install, avoid using it! Since coding-standards most of the time are required in Require-Dev.
4. Remove the package phpcompatibility (if applied to your composer.json)

   ```
   $ composer remove phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
   ```
5. Remove from script section the following snippet because it won't work for PHP81:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "post-install-cmd": [
           "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility)"
       ],
       "post-update-cmd": [
           "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility)"
       ]
   }
   ```